# how to generate lazy iteration thing in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

currently I am still doing this question :

> Make a general purpose infinite sequence initialisation function that
>   creates infinite lazy sequences. It will take as parameter a function
>   to compute the next value from the current value. In other words, it
>   should be a “factory” for functions like naturalNumbers. Thus, if we
>   call our function initSequence, then initSequence(n=>n+1) will return
>   a function equivalent to naturalNumbers.

this template is given

```
    interface LazySequence<T> {
    value: T;
    next(): LazySequence<T>;
}

// Implement the function:
function initSequence<T>(transform: (value: T) => T): (initialValue: T) => LazySequence<T>
{
    // Your code here 
}
```

So far, this is my code in TypeScript

```
interface LazySequence<T> {
    value: T;
    next(): LazySequence<T>;
}

// Implement the function:
function initSequence<T>(transform: (value: T) => T): (initialValue: T) => LazySequence<T>
{
    // Your code here ...
    return () => initSequence(v=>v+1) => LazySequence;
}
```

and it seemed like the code doesn't work accordingly. can anybody help? then can anybody make a clear explanation regarding lazy evaluation, lazy iteration and another lazy things?
thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an existing tool for this, like generators (built into the language) or observables (via a library like Rx)?

Comment: Your code doesn't even seem to typecheck. Or do I miss something?

Comment: It seems like a 'homework'. If that is the case, please refer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you need to use the given interface or not, but it seems like you need generator function. Read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

An example can be as follows:

```
// A generic infinite sequence generator function.
function* infiniteSequence<T>(initialValue: T, transform: (value: T) => T): IterableIterator<T> {
    while (true) {
        yield initialValue;
        initialValue = transform(initialValue);
    }
}

// create different sequences using the generic sequence generator function.

let intSequence = infiniteSequence(1, n => n + 1); // sequence of natural numbers
console.log(intSequence.next().value); // 1
console.log(intSequence.next().value); // 2
console.log(intSequence.next().value); // 3 

let oddSequence = infiniteSequence(1, n => n + 2); // sequence of odd numbers
console.log(oddSequence.next().value); // 1
console.log(oddSequence.next().value); // 3
console.log(oddSequence.next().value); // 5

let evenSequence = infiniteSequence(0, n => n + 2); // sequence of even numbers
console.log(evenSequence.next().value); // 0
console.log(evenSequence.next().value); // 2 
console.log(evenSequence.next().value); // 4
```

---

**Update based on OP's comment:**

As this question seems like a homework, I will just try to provide some useful hints.

1. Think about the return type of `initSequence` which is `(initialValue: T) => LazySequence<T>`, but you are returning `() => initSequence(v=>v+1) => LazySequence`, which does not match the required return type. In other words you need to return a function which takes a value of type `T` returns a *object* of type `LazySequence<T>`. Read about arrow functions in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html).
2. Think about how you can construct an *object* of an interface. Hint: Duck Typing. Read about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).
3. The last bit of this problem is to construct the `next` method and `value` property. Note that `next` again returns a *object* of type `LazySequence<T>`, where `value` should be the next value in the sequence(this is the part I am assuming). Note that `initSequence(...)(...)` can return such an object.

Have fun :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually the given interface is needed to be implemented. I am just confused how to use it properly

Comment: @phoenixdamn88 As your question seems to be a homework question, I have updated my answer with some hints. Hope it helps.